# Python insert at regex position

Tags: python, regex

I'm working in Python, and I have some strings contain **special characters** like

*"My name is * and he is *"*.

I want to find all special characters in the string and insert "**\**" before it so it should be:

*"My name is \* and he is \*"*.

The regex expression I use to spot special characters is `` r'[-._!"`\'#%&,:;<>=@{}~\$\(\)\*\+\/\\\?\[\]\^\|]+' ``. Is there an easy approach for this in Python?

Comment: Yes, replace with `r'\\\g<0>'`.

Comment: Pretty close but it gave me "My name is \\\* and he is \\\*", the \ is duplicated

Comment: No, it wokrs as you need. You just do not use `print`, and see the console output that yields string literals, not literal strings.

Comment: See the answer and code demo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to replace with `r'\\\g<0>'`:

```py
import re
rx = r'[][._!"`\'#%&,:;<>=@{}~$()*+/\\?^|-]+'
text = "My name is * and he is *"
print( re.sub(rx, r'\\\g<0>', text) )
# => My name is \* and he is \*
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/aIccJj).

*Replacement pattern details*:

- `\\` - a single literal backslash (the double backslash is used since `\` is special in replacement patterns)
- `\g<0>` - a backreference to the whole match value.

Answer (score 0):

you are just taking it too far with regex a simple replace method can solve this with ease

example:

```
string = "Hello my name is * I live in *\nI am ^ years old I live with my %"
special_characters = ['*', '^', '%']

for char in special_characters:
    string = string.replace(char, f'\{char}')
    
print(string)
```

output:

> Hello my name is \* I live in \*

> I am \^ years old I live with my \%